# Call multiple variables using for loop

Tags: r

I want to combine two data frames from variable list using for loop. I am using following code for creating and combining data frame column wise.

```
tu1<-data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(2,5,6))
tu2<-data.frame(c(5,5,37),c(21,52,61))
Consolidate<-function(){
  tx<-data.frame(0)
  for(i in :2){
    namefile1<-paste("tu",as.character(i),sep = "")
    tr<-namefile1
    tx<-data.frame(cbind(tr,tx))
  }
  tx
}
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I have 117 data frame from tu1 to tu117. I want to combine them column wise.

Comment: Do you have similar column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use one liner as below:

```
do.call(cbind, mget(ls(pattern="^tu\\d+")))
```

It will combine all data frames with similar patterns in your case "tu".

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

OP explained that: "I have 117 data frame from tu1 to tu117. I want to combine them column wise". To do so he can:

```
foo <- grep("tu[1-117]", ls(), value = TRUE)
tuAll <- do.call(cbind, sapply(foo, function(x) get(x)))
```

**Old answer:**

I can't imagine why would you want to do this as simple `cbind(tu1, tu2)` works. If you want to bind multiple times you can use `cbind(tu1, tu2, tu1, tu2)`.

But if you want to bind them using loop (not recommending) this is edited version of your `Consolidate()` function:

```
tu1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(2,5,6))
tu2 <- data.frame(c(5,5,37), c(21,52,61))
Consolidate <- function() {
    for(i in 1:2){
        namefile <- paste0("tu", i)
        if (i == 1) {
            tx <- get(namefile)
        } else {
            tx <- cbind(get(namefile), tx)
        }
    }
    return(tx)
}
```